# NUnit- No Suitable Constructor was Found

Tags: c#, nunit

Trying to test something with NUnit 3. I have a `Country` object that I'm trying to test out.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Country : IComparable
{
    private String countryName;
    private float GDP;
    private float inflation;
    private float tradeBalance;
    private float HDIRanking;
    private List<String> tradePartners;
    private String displayPartnersInTable; //used to display trade partners in Data table, turns list into string with commas to be displayed nicely
    Country c;


    public Country(String countryName, float GDP, float inflation, float tradeBalance, float HDIRanking, List<String> tradePartners)
    {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.GDP = GDP;
        this.inflation = inflation;
        this.tradeBalance = tradeBalance;
        this.HDIRanking = HDIRanking;
        this.tradePartners = tradePartners;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        List<String> l = new List<string>();
        l.Add("UK");
        Country c = new Country("Malta", (float)1.2, (float)2.3, (float)3.2, 1, new List<string>() { "UK" });
    }

    [Test]
    public void CountryTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Malta", c.countryName, "Wrong country");
    }
```

Keep getting an error saying no suitable constructor was found. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: As soon as it hits the CountryTest() method @Neijwiert

Comment: Maybe just copy and paste the exact error message, cause "as soon as it hits the CountryTest() method" is not very helpful

Comment: Maybe you need an empty constructor? public Country() ?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmin Cretu is correct. In NUnit v3, You need to add default parameter-less constructor for test fixture, 'Country'. Add it.

```
public Country() { }
```

Possible duplicate of this case, [Nunit test gives result OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722194/nunit-test-gives-result-onetimesetup-no-suitable-constructor-was-found)